# Python - Drop date from data set using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and I wanted to test a simple online ML application using TensorFlow and pandas. I want to drop the Date column and I looked online at the Pandas documentation for dropping a column from the data variable, but I'm still having an issue.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete a column from a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-a-column-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation of `drop`.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

```py
data.drop(columns='Date')
```

or

```py
data.drop('Date', axis=1)
```

Comment: Ah, I must have seem some former documentation. Thank you - I just removed the brackets and it resolved the issue.