# How to drop multiple columns in a csv using pandas read_csv and then save down the csv file?

Tags: pandas, csv

I have tried a number of ways to drop multiple columns in a csv using `read_csv` and then save down the new csv (with the columns deleted), but none of them work. Here is my latest:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('TradedInstrument_20230331_real.csv',  sep='\t', encoding='unicode_escape')
df.drop(columns='stopTrdgAllowedInOpnFlag')
df.drop(columns='stopTrdgsAllowableInTrdg')
df.drop(columns='preTradeBlockThresholdChf')
df.drop(columns='billingSegmentCode')
df.drop(columns='preTradeBlockThresholdChf')
df.drop(columns='billingSegmentDesc').to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

This only removes the `billingSegmentDesc`.

Comment: what is your initial `df.columns` ?

Comment: Ahh let me include it in the question.

Comment: [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) is not inplace by default. Add `inplace=True`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete a column from a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-a-column-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Ahh no wonder. One sec @BigBen it does answer the deleting multiple columns, but not sure about when I save it down. Let me try it, and if it does I'll close the Q.

Comment: Or if you don't want to use `inplace`, then `cols = ['stopTrdgAllowedInOpnFlag', 'stopTrdgsAllowableInTrdg', ...]`, then `df.drop(columns=cols).to_csv(...)`. Either way, the linked duplicate covers both `inplace` and dropping multiple columns.

Comment: Amazing, thanks Ben. That's so helpful

Answer (score 1):

Answer was stated in the comments by BigBen, but like they said, `df.drop` is not an inplace function.  You need to do
`df = df.drop(columns=colname)` or `df.drop(columns=colname, inplace=True`.
That being said, you can also drop many at once by including just a list.

```py
input_file_name = 'data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(input_file_name)

cols_to_drop = ['colname1, colname2']
df = df.drop(columns=cols_to_drop)

output_file_name = 'processed_data.csv'
df.to_csv(output_file_name, index=False)

# `index=False` should be default, without it it saves the index 
# which is like super annoying when included.
```